# Customize bootstrap-select text colors

Tags: css, bootstrap-select

I'm having a hard time changing the colors in my select.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select name="mySelect" class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="id_mySelect"></select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();   

  $("#id_mySelect").html(
    '<option value="0">[Nothing selected]</option>'
    +'<option value="1">Option 1</option>'
    +'<option value="2">Option 2</option>'
  )
  $("#id_mySelect").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

I'd like to know how to:

1. Change color of the first option [Nothing selected] when select menu is closed?
2. Change color when there are chosen other select options when select menu is closed?
3. Change option's color when the select menu is opened?
4. Change color when option on hover when select menu is opened?
5. Change background color of the whole select menu when it is opened?

   [Here is jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz46v9mx/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CSS-Only Solution

Here is a stack snippet that shows how to change the colors of the requested components:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();

  $("#id_mySelect").html(
    '<option value="0">[Nothing selected]</option>' +
    '<option value="1">Option 1</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Option 2</option>'
  )
  $("#id_mySelect").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

```css
.selectContainer {
  width: 200px
}

/* 1. Change color of the first option [Nothing selected] when select menu is closed? */
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle[title="[Nothing selected]"] .filter-option {
  color: red;
}

/* 2. Change color when there are chosen other select options when select menu is closed? */
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
  color: blue;
}

/* 3. Change option's color when the select menu is opened? */
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: green;
}

/* 4. Change color when option on hover when select menu is opened? */
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover:not(:focus) {
  color: orange;
}

/* 5. Change background color of the whole select menu when is opened? */
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectContainer">
  <select name="mySelect" class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="id_mySelect"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great answer! This is what I needed! One more question: can you modify the answer 4 (if it's possible with css) so it won't affect `a:focus` option? (only hover on non-selected options)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: I just noticed that it doesn't work `:not(:focus)` when select has `data-live-search="true"` [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz46v9mx/13/) any idea how to fix it? (I have mainly without live-search but a few selects are with)

Comment: @felixRo It looks like it adds a `selected` class to the `li` element and removes the `:focus` pseudo class. So I added a `:not(.selected)` to the `li` to also exclude the `selected` class. This should handle both cases. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uz46v9mx/14/

Comment: Thank you for explaining because I could change my previous `.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {background-color: green}` to `.dropdown-menu > li.selected > a {background-color: green}`. Everything seems to be working fine now. Thank you once more!

Answer (score 2):

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/uz46v9mx/7/) the fiddle
//Change color of the first option [Nothing selected] when select menu is closed

```
$('.filter-option').css("color","red");

//event click a class is set on .pickerSelectClass but not yet 

$('.pickerSelectClass').click(function() {

  //menu option is open 
  if(!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
  //Change option's color when the select menu is opened
  //Change background color of the whole select menu when is opened
    $('.dropdown-menu a').css({
      'background':'none',
      'color': 'red'
      });
    //Change color when option on hover when select menu is opened
  $('.dropdown-menu a').hover(
  function() {
        $(this).css({
      'background':'none',
      'color': 'blue'
      });
  }, function() {
        $(this).css({
      'background':'none',
      'color': 'red'
      });
  }
);
  $('.dropdown-menu').css('background','green');
  //close
  }else {
  //color of button when option selected
       $('.filter-option').css("color","blue");
  }

  });
```